# разделить json на json файлы

Tags: json

Есть следующий json:

```
{id:1, name:"мама" },
{id:2, name:"папа"},
{id:3, name:"бабушка"}
```

Как разделить json на 
{id:1, name:"мама" } {id:2, name:"папа"} {id:3, name:"бабушка"} отдельные файлы?

Comment: К сожалению, это не json

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали, чем надо воспользоваться для решения задачи и не описали, что именно у вас не получается, так что я использовал bash.

Записал ваш файл:

```
$ echo "{id:1, name:"мама" }, {id:2, name:"папа"}, {id:3, name:"бабушка"}" > original.json
```

Произнёс магическое заклинание:

```
$ cat original.json | sed 's/\}\,/}\n/g' | while read LINE; do if [ ${#LINE} > 0 ]; then echo "$LINE" > result$i.txt; i=$(( $i + 1 )); fi  done
```

Вуаля, отдельные файлики:

```
$ grep "" result*txt
result.txt:{id:1, name:мама }
result1.txt:{id:2, name:папа}
result2.txt:{id:3, name:бабушка}
```